# Drawing numbers from an interval

Tags: probability

We draw $10$ numbers from an interval $[0,5]$. Compute probability, that at least two of these numbers will land in $[1,3]$.

So if $A-$ at least two numbers land in an interval $[1,3]$, then:

$A'-$ none of the numbers or only one will land in $[1,3]$, and it gives me:

$\Bbb P(A')=\frac{\lambda_{10}([0,1)\cup(3,5])+10 \cdot\lambda_{9}([0,1)\cup(3,5])\cdot\lambda_1([1,3]) }{\lambda_{10}([0,5])}$

where $\lambda_a$ is a Lebesgue measure for a  cartesian product of intervals  in $\Bbb R^a.$

Then

$\Bbb P(A)=1-\Bbb P(A')=1-\frac{\lambda_{10}([0,1)\cup(3,5])+10 \cdot\lambda_{9}([0,1)\cup(3,5])\cdot\lambda_1([1,3]) }{\lambda_{10}([0,5])}=1-\frac{3^{10}+10*3^9*2}{5^{10}}=0.9536$

Am I right? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct.  Here's another way to express it:
$$\sum_{k=2}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k}
=1-\sum_{k=0}^1 \binom{n}{k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k}
=1-(1-p)^n-n p (1-p)^{n-1}
$$

Now take $n=10$ and $p=(3-1)/(5-0)=2/5$.

Comment: Nice. answer (+1)